# confusion about node.js scoping

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a client for mpd (music player daemon) with node, using the [node-mpdsocket](https://github.com/ewenig/node-mpdsocket) library, but I appear to have run into a bit of confusion early on. In this example, `response` is an object, and `response['state']` should return a string.

```
var togglePause = function() {
  var mpdState;

  mpd.send('status', function(response) {
    mpdState = response.state;

    // Here, console.log(mpdState) returns mpd's state correctly
    console.log(mpdState);
  });

  // Here, undefined is returned regardless of mpd's actual state
  console.log(mpdState);
}
```

I expected `mpdState` to return a string in both instances because both places where `console.log` are called are within the same function. However, this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: In the `mpd.send` callback function where you set `mpdState` is actually asynchronous. So your last `console.log` actually executes first and it is `undefined` at the point of time.

Comment: The issue isn't scope. `mpdState` is in scope to throughout `togglePause`. The issue is execution order. Since `mpd.send()` is asynchronous, `togglePause` doesn't execute entirely top-to-bottom. Related: [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: You can't return a value that is set from an asynchronous function. You have to get that value using callbacks. One of the most searched questions in JavaScript arty stack overflow

Comment: Great, thanks guys! If someone wants to submit one of your comments as an answer, I'd love to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback passed to `mpd.send` is being invoked asynchronously.  So, the second `console.log` statement is being called before the callback is ever run.  The `console.log` statement inside the callback has the correct value as you can see.

The code you are running is behaving as expected.

Comment: i have put the same thing in the comment.